# 403 Error with Java Applet viewer in Websphere

Tags: java, applet, websphere, appletviewer, java-security

My application is using java appletviewer to view the images. But i am getting the below error and found it in Java console log.

Java Plug-in 1.6.0_27
Using JRE version 1.6.0_27-b07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\rkosuri

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

---

```
Creating instance of com.powertechnology.viewer.connect.DirectConnector
IOException caught!
URL=http://11.22.33.44:9080/my_app_context/AppletPak/jsp/viewer/../../ViewerGetConfig?
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://11.22.33.44:9080/my_app_context/AppletPak/jsp/viewer/../../ViewerGetConfig?
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.connect.TDPConnector.getPage(TDPConnector.java:576)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.connect.TDPConnector.getSettings(TDPConnector.java:111)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.TDPViewer.start(TDPViewer.java:232)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.TDPViewerApplet.start(TDPViewerApplet.java:80)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.powertechnology.viewer.connect.TDPConnector.getPage(TDPConnector.java:614)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.connect.TDPConnector.getSettings(TDPConnector.java:111)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.TDPViewer.start(TDPViewer.java:232)
at com.powertechnology.viewer.TDPViewerApplet.start(TDPViewerApplet.java:80)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When i copy and paste and below in browser url, i am able to view the all the properties of appletviewer.

http://11.22.33.44:9080/my_app_context/AppletPak/jsp/viewer/../../ViewerGetConfig?

I dont know where i am missing it. No logs at server end. I think, at browser stage it is getting restricted by some security. I am using IE11 for the same. IS there any issue with servlets deployments ??? First thing is it is not reaching server as far i know.

Your suggestions are more valuable. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. But, i have enabled java applet in IE under security. Still i am getting the same.

Comment: One more input like, it actually failing at input = urlConnection.getInputStream(); . I tried with few sample URL's like google.com and i am getting response back to my code. But with my application URL as mentioned above ,  i am getting IOException. Do i need to add anything in web.xml of my war file..

Comment: What type of authentication scheme are you using on the server side? Basic? Some type of single sign on?

Comment: Its basic. Because in login page itself i had singlesignon check box and i am not check in. So, singlesignon is false. It should be basic. I suspect the URL here.Is ../ is allowed in URL ??"http://11.22.33.44:9080/my_app_context/AppletPak/jsp/viewer/../../ViewerGetConfig".

Comment: Any observations from any one ???

Comment: I have observed this in logfile.  "<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/></soapenv:Header>". This is the last statement i am getting and after thereafter i am getting error